# Php utf raw url decode

Tags: php, url, decode

*I have checked various resources online without success.*

I want to decode url

```
http://link/%E0%A8%B9%E0%A9%8B%E0%A8%B2%E0%A9%80/
```

to

```
http://link/ਹੋਲੀ/
```

as working here: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/rawurldecode

Comment: [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

Comment: or just use `urldecode` https://3v4l.org/lHAD4 ??

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `rawurldecode` function in PHP:

```
$newUrl = rawurldecode($oldUrl);
echo $newUrl;
```